# String comparison returns false. Strange javascript behaviour with jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I started to create a todo list with jQuery mobile in order to learn it better. I'm listening to the events coming from the buttons of a menu like this:

```
        me.selectedTarget = me.menuNode.find(".ui-btn").first();

        me.menuNode.on("click", ".ui-btn", function (e) {
            var target =  $(e.currentTarget)
                ,targetText = target.text();
            console.debug("Click on'", targetText,"'" );
            if(target === me.selectedTarget) return;

            if(targetText == "View To Do "){
                core.pub("view:todo");
            } else if(targetText == "View Done ") {
                core.pub("view:done");
            } else {
                me.selectedTarget.click();
            }
            me.selectedTarget = target;
        });
```

The variable targetText has one extra " " space at the end for some reason. I have 3 buttons, but the third one is a bit special - not relevant anyway -.

[image: the buttons that this code listens to.]

My problem is that I'm always getting on the last else clause. targetText never get's to be equal to "View To Do " or "View Done ".

Why isn't "View Done " == "View Done "? ~X(

[image: firebug debugging results]

[image: the html markup]

Comment: My guess is that the trailing space is missing, why not do $.trim("View Done ") == $.trim("View Done ")?  Your string may have gotten a \t \r or \n that shows up as a space in the dubugger.

Comment: Maybe `$.trim` will help. Remove extra 'space' from string literals and trim `targetText`-> `$.trim(targetText)=="View Done"`

Comment: I didn't know there was a trim in jQuery :O

Comment: @Engineer you saved my day... apparently this stupid dumb and people-killing problem continue to exist today. I was working in Angular 2 and I did a pure js trim on the string and it's working... I lost my mind for something like 2 hours!
Thank you again.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The comparison is failing because the strings are not the same. So the question really is **why** are they not the same? Apparently the space in one of the strings is not the standard space character (Unicode has more than one space), or one of the strings has an invisible character in it (Unicode has those, too).

So to find out what's going on, I'd do this:

```
for (let index = 0; index < targetText.length; ++index) {
    console.log(`char at ${index}: ${targetText.charCodeAt(index)}`);
}
```

...and the same with your string literal in your code (not retyping it, but moving it into a local and then outputting that; since if you retype it, you'll presumably type the normal space). Compare the sequences of character codes and you'll find the discrepancy.

Comment: the trim suggestion did the job for me. I guess I should consider that two things that look the same, could have different representations.

Comment: @VladNicula: Indeed they can. :-) I'd be curious to know what non-space whitespace you had in there...

Comment: I Added a screenshot of the HTML. There is no space visible in there. However I do recall copying the first two links from the jQuery Docs. Maybe the copy+paste added something behind the scenes, since the .text() returned the extra space.

Comment: @VladNicula: Interesting! Just for my benefit and out of curiousity, feel free not to bother, but I'd love to see the output of the code above when you click the "View Done" link.

Comment: "View Done" should be 9 chars long. It's 10. 
char 0=: 86
char 1=: 105
char 2=: 101
char 3=: 119
char 4=: 32
char 5=: 68
char 6=: 111
char 7=: 110
char 8=: 101
char 9=: 160

Comment: Also, it was not copy paste related. I tried with a typed markup. The extra space is still there. I'm using the RC version of jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Sure enough, it (the character at the end) was a non-breaking space, Unicode character 160 -- aka [U+00A0](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/NamesList.txt). If the non-breaking space isn't in the markup, I wonder why it's showing up in the DOM element. Interesting, thanks for letting me know what the codes were.

Comment: I found out why this happens. jQuery Mobile adds a &nbsp; in a span tag that creates the shadow of the buttons. My guess is that the .text() method is not the best way to get the text out of a jQ Mobile button. I think there is a special function for that... or maybe the label of the button is not intended for such use.

Comment: @VladNicula: not only spaces … I just spent some time with "Μπιφτεκι γεμιστο" and "Μπιφτεκι γεμιστo" 
Spoiler: one "o" is greek the other is latin,