# Two seemingly equal strings not equal in javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I have 2 strings and I am trying to compare them. 
I print them with quotes to make sure that there is no whitespace characters. 
Then i use the equality operator to see if they are equal.
Here is the result

```
'! Invite to Troy Florida Event'
'! Invite to Troy Florida Event'
false
```

Here is the code that creates the output:

```
"\'"+ String(list_name) + 
"\'<BR/>\'" + 
String(dialer_list_selections[5][0]) +  "\'<BR/>" + 
String(String(list_name) === String(dialer_list_selections[5][0]))
```

Any ideas how i can debug this and what is going on?

All the other strings in the list work correctly.

Printing the strings character code by character code does reveal that they are indeed different.

```
Using this code for both and strings and printing I get.
    test_string = "";
    for (index = 0; index < String(list_name).length; ++index) {
        test_string +=  "," +String(list_name).charCodeAt(index);
    }

33,32,73,110,118,105,116,101,32,116,111,32,84,114,111,121,32,70,108,111,114,105,100,97,32,69,118,101,110,116
33,32,32,73,110,118,105,116,101,32,116,111,32,84,114,111,121,32,70,108,111,114,105,100,97,32,69,118,101,110,116
```

Now is there a way to make sure that the string comparison returns true if the strings look the same when printed even though they have different charCodes and lengths?

Comment: When I copy-paste the two strings in the upper snippet, they _are_ equal. Please include the relevant variables for the lower snippet.

Comment: Can you post one of the working examples?

Comment: How exactly do you print these out, I am thinking that it might be an issue with the way you log it, rather then the  strings themselves

Comment: When i do this `String(String('! Invite to Troy Florida Event') === String('! Invite to Troy Florida Event'))` in chrome console, the result is `"true"`, so are you sure the strings are actually equal? without the variants values its hard to understand the issue, you might try to put a snippet of your variants here, because the issue is not with the comparison.

Comment: @Dellirium I create a test string then i used $( ".class" ).html(test_string); but i dont think its a logging issue since I am testing it because it doesnt work in an if statement down below or at least not the only issue

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String comparison returns false. Strange javascript behaviour with jQuery mobile. \[code included\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154898/string-comparison-returns-false-strange-javascript-behaviour-with-jquery-mobile)

Comment: Thing is, what you output in an HTML element can sometimes be different then what you have in your variable, take for example "a   (many spaces here... cant print it out)    a" in a variable is exactly like that, outputting it to an html element you will get a "a a", so in reality your two strings could indeed be different

Comment: @Liam I will try I was hoping I was missing something that can be resolved without it. I just dont understand how 2 strings can print the same and not be equal.

Comment: @Xitcod13 take the time to read the answer in the link I posted and you'll know how can two strings not be equal.

Comment: @Xitcod13 because $().html() is not print, use console.log( though mind you even this can be a lie)

Comment: *I just dont understand how 2 strings can print the same and not be equal* because encoding. What you see as a string can be encoded multiple ways. For example a space in HTML can be represented as an "actual space",  `&nbsp;` or `&#160;`. These 3 things look the same but are not equal. The actual solution here will depend on what your issue is which we cannot determine from the code you've posted

Comment: You can be confident that the result *will* be true if you are really comparing two identical strings, so clearly you've made a mistake somewhere. DO use console.log(), encase strings with delimiters such as "[" and "]", consider printing the length and take advantage of the log functions accepting an arbitrary number of parameters. DON'T turn output into HTML unless you have to, and if you do, emit the content within a <pre> block.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy Thanks your comment helps a lot. It is a clear explanation of how those strings must be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem seem to be the comparison of two similar string with different whitespace characters. Why not remove alls whitespace characters before comparing them ? You can do it with a regexp like `somestring.replace(/\s+/g, "")`.

So, your test becomes

```
String(
    String(list_name.replace(/\s+/g, "")) === 
    String(dialer_list_selections[5][0].replace(/\s+/g, ""))
)
```

Comment: Thanks, although I needed to replace the white spaces with a whitespace of a common type so that strings that dont look the same dont give a false positive `list_name.replace(/\s+/g, " ")`

Comment: In general, removing the whitespaces will cause wrong result when compare.

E.g.: 
"!Invite to Troy Florida Event" is different than 
"! Invite to TroyFlorida Event"

Without white spaces they are equal. Which is wrong!